# A clarification in a para in SGA4.5

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

This is a para from SGA4.5 that I have confusion in.[image]
The situation gives us an $A$-torsor $T \longrightarrow X$ for a finite group $A$. And we also have a group homomorphism $\rho : A \longrightarrow GL(V)$. I am unable to make sense of the equation (1.2.2) and the text preceding it. As I understand, $T$ over $X$ has a local trivialisation in étale topology whose fibres are $A$. This gives us a 1-cocycle (again, in étale topology) $U_i \times_{X} U_j \xrightarrow{c_{ij}} A$, which when composed with $\rho$ gives a $V$-torsor on $X$. The associated sheaf is what I suppose called $\mathcal F$. What I need help is how one obtains the map (1.2.2) in the text. According to the author, it is a map of sheaves. How is $\textrm{Isom}(V,\mathcal F)$ (``Isom" denotes the set of isomorphisms) a sheaf? It seems to me to be covariant from the étale site on $X$, because of the Hom. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Composing with $\rho$ should give us a $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ torsor $C$, which will determine a local system $\mathcal{F}$ such that $C$ is the torsor of isomorphisms between $\mathcal{F}$ and the trivial local system $V$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand yet. According to what you say $\mathcal F$ has fibres $GL(V)$, whereas $C$ has fibres $V$. So what is the isomorphism. On the contrary what I said seems a natural enough construction.